# What is the mvc action equivalent to helper.Content("~/")?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view helpers I can do this:

```
helper.Content("~/")
```

And this returns the correct root url value (say if it is a domain + folder setup in IIS).

What is the equivalent for a controller action method?  Can I use these helpers from inside of an action also somehow?

Comment: Why not you give it a try? :/ I am sure if it works it will show the output, otherwise you would see an exception! :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside a controller:

```
Url.Content("~/");
```

In a view:

```
@Url.Content("~/")
```

Comment: In a view you can just use `<img src="~/Content/.." />` as well.